# Static assert in CRTP class hierarchy that derived class does not implement a certain method

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, crtp

I have a class hierarchy using CRTP. The base class defines an interface I cannot change (inside another library). It has some `impl` methods that derived classes may "override" (shadow) to specialize the behaviour.

Now, I would like to introduce a new base class that inherits from the original base class, and adapts this interface. I.e., it implements some of the `impl` methods and offers new ones. I would like to check in this intermediate class that the `impl` methods that I implement are **not** implemented by the final derived class. Instead, the final derived class should use the new, adapted `impl` methods.

Let's give an example (full example: https://godbolt.org/z/9bWrezPv3).

The base class interface that can't be changed is:

```cpp
template <class Derived>
struct Greeter {
    void greet() {
        cout << "Hello ";
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->greetImpl();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    void greetImpl() {
        cout << "world";
    }
};
```

Usual usage would be:

```cpp
struct MyGreeter: public Greeter<MyGreeter> {
    void greetImpl() {
        cout << "WORLD";
    }
};
```

Now, I'd like to offer additional common functionality, by introducing the intermediate base class.

```cpp
template <class Derived>
struct ExcitedGreeter: public Greeter<Derived> {
    using Base = Greeter<Derived>;

    void greetImpl() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->greetCamlyImpl();
        cout << "!!!";
    }

    void greetCamlyImpl() {
        Base::greetImpl();
    }
};
```

Users of `ExcitedGreeter` should now implement `greetCamlyImpl`. If they instead implement `greetImpl`, the functionality is broken, for example:

```cpp
struct MyWorkingGreeter: public ExcitedGreeter<MyWorkingGreeter> {
    void greetCamlyImpl() {
        cout << "beautiful world";
    }
};

struct MyBuggyGreeter: public ExcitedGreeter<MyBuggyGreeter> {
    // Ooops, forgot to switch from `greetImpl` to `greetCamlyImpl` when 
    // changing the base class from `Greeter` to `ExcitedGreeter`...
    void greetImpl() {
        cout << "buggy world";
    }
};
```

`MyWorkingGreeter::greet` prints `Hello beautiful world!!!`, while `MyBuggyGreeter::greet` prints `Hello buggy world`. The latter is not as excited as it should be...

My question is, how can I statically assert that `MyBuggyGreeter` does not implement `greetImpl()` inside the definition of `ExcitedGreeter`? Two things I tried are checking the type of `&Derived::greetImpl`:

```cpp
using This = ExcitedGreeter<Derived>;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&Derived::greetImpl), void (This::*)()>::value);
```

and also comparing function pointers:

```cpp
static_assert(&Derived::greetImpl == &This::greetImpl);
```

I tried placing these checks in the definition of `ExcitedGreeter::greetImpl`.

But in both cases it seems `Derived::greetImpl` always resolves to `ExcitedGreeter::greetImpl`, for both `MyWorkingGreeter` and `MyBuggyGreeter`.

Any idea why that's the case and how to rectify this?

Comment: [final](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: Unfortunately, `final` only works for virtual functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mascoj's answer is good and shows the alternative like passing `ExcitedGreeter` to `Greeter` as a template argument instead of `Derived`. This ensures `greetImpl()` from `ExcitedGreeter` are always called from `greet()`, but it doesn't lead to an error if the derived class also implements `greetImpl()` by accident. The discussion made me realize why my attempted static asserts in the question didn't work and how to fix it.

The reason the static asserts didn't work originally is that I placed them inside `ExcitedGreeter::greetImpl()`. When it is shadowed by `MyBuggyGreeter::greetImpl()`, its a method that is never called. Due to SFINAE, the compiler simply omits the function from the class definition and does not generate an error.

If instead we place the static asserts in the destructor, it behaves as intended. Either assert variant that I described in the question works fine, but I find comparing function pointer addresses a bit easier to read / comprehend:

```cpp
    ~ExcitedGreeter() {
        using This = ExcitedGreeter<Derived>;
        static_assert(&Derived::greetImpl == &This::greetImpl &&
            "Don't shadow `greetImpl()`; instead implement `greetCalmlyImpl()`.");
    }
```

Working example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vK6fjGoP5)

PS: One source of error is still that if you misspell `greetCalmlyImpl()`, you don't get any error. Your specialized implementation is just never called. That's a general issue with this static polymorphism and the same issue is present already in the interface of `Greeter`. It could be solved if C++ supported something like `final` and `override` for non-virtual methods. It's ironic that in my original example I misspelled the function `greetCamlyImpl()`...

Answer (score 3):

Your logic isn't exactly right for adapting the interface and by providing `Derived` to the `Base`, it allows the `Base` to completely bypass your intermediate: `ExcitedGreeter`.

How to solve this? Don't provide `Derived` all the way up your chain.

```cpp
template <class Derived>
struct ExcitedGreeter: public Greeter<ExcitedGreeter> {
    using Base = Greeter<ExcitedGreeter>;

    void greetImpl() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->greetCamlyImpl();
        cout << "!!!";
    }

    void greetCamlyImpl() {
        Base::greetImpl();
    }
};
```

This will force the `Base` class to leverage the `ExcitedGreeter` which can then complete the chain with your current implementation as the `Base` can only call the `greetImpl` in your `ExcitedGreeter` class.

To ensure that `Derived` provides an "override" (not really an override), a `static_assert` can be used to check if the `ExcitedGreeter`'s `greetImpl` was shadowed or not in the `Derived`:

```cpp
 static_assert(&ExcitedGreeter<Derived>::greetImpl == &Derived::greetImpl)
```

Simplified example:

```
template<class Child>
class A
{
  public:
    void my_func(){printf("Do a thing");}
};


class B : public A<B>
{
    public:
    void my_func(){printf("Shadowed");}
};

static_assert(&A<B>::my_func != &B::my_func);
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ETzvYdnvn)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the answer. I see how this ensures that the final derived class' `greetImpl()` is not called from `greet()`, but it does not really prevent the accidental bugs for someone switching from using `Greeter` as a base class to `ExcitedGreeter`. If they forget to rename their `greetImpl()` to `greetCalmlyImpl()`, it would compile fine, just that the `greetImpl()` of the derived class is silently ignored. `ExcitedGreeter` would call `Base::greetImpl()` via it's own `greetCamlyImpl()`. It's a different failure, but the same kind of bug potential as in my original code.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel I'm not sure there is a way to prevent function shadowing using static polymorphism, but I could be wrong. Do you require the `greetCamlyImpl` in the `ExcitedGreeter`? That's essentially what is breaking your CRTP contract of forcing implementation of `greetCalmyImpl` in the `Derived`, removing it would fail to compile if `greetCalmlyImpl` did not exist in the `Derived`

Comment: yeah, this is what we are doing at the moment. The reason we would like to have the default `greetCamlyImpl()` inside `ExcitedGreeter` though, is that in the actual code there are multiple different methods with their `impl` variants. Derived classes typically only need to provide a few and usually not all of time. With this approach, however, we force everyone to implement all of them. But at least it leads to a compile error and prompts you to double check the interface definition of `ExcitedGreeter` if you switch from `Greeter`.

Comment: Why do say you think it's not possible to check this at compile time? When the compiler sees `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->greetCamlyImpl();` in the `ExcitedGreeter`, it must know which function call to place, `ExcitedGreeter::greetCamlyImpl()` or `Derived::greetCamlyImpl()`. So it must be able to tell if `greetCamlyImpl()` exists in `Derived`. Question is, how can we squeeze the information out of the compiler and why does `static_assert(&Derived::greetImpl == &This::greetImpl)` not work? Btw, a check that works at runtime would also be helpful.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel Because by adding `greetCamlyImpl` to `ExcitedGreeter` the `Derived` class is inheriting that function. I believe that `static_assert` does not function as you intend since an inherited function isn't the same function pointer as the base's....

Comment: Okay double checking, you should be able to use that static assert, let me update my answer.

Comment: That's the same static assert I already have in my question. But your reply made me realize why the static check in my question didn't work. Thanks for the update, but I believe a vital point to explain where we need to place this static assert to make sure it works as intended is missing to answer the question. I typed up an answer myself that hopefully illustrates this. I hope that's ok.